# Error using GetExtendedTcpTable in python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, tcp, ctypes

I've got some troubles with using "GetExtendedTcpTable". When I tried to run my script, i've got message like this:

> AssertionError: [Error 0] The operation completed successfully

Rarely script working normally, I dont understand this message, Operation completed, what`s wrong?

This is code, i tried to execute:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
from socket import  inet_aton,   inet_ntoa,  htons


AF_INET = 2
TCP_TABLE_BASIC_LISTENER = 0
TCP_TABLE_BASIC_CONNECTIONS = 1
TCP_TABLE_BASIC_ALL = 2
TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_LISTENER = 3
TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS = 4
TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL = 5
TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_LISTENER = 6
TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_CONNECTIONS = 7
TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_ALL = 8

# for storing socket info python style.  
class socket_info:

    State = None
    LocalAddr = None
    LocalPort = None
    RemoteAddr = None
    RemotePort = None

    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):

        for key, word in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, word)

def formatip (ip):
    ip = inet_aton (str(ip))
    return inet_ntoa (ip[::-1])

states = {
    1 : "TCP_STATE_CLOSED",
    2 : "TCP_STATE_LISTEN",
    3 : "TCP_STATE_SYN_SENT",
    4 : "TCP_STATE_SYN_RCVD",
    5 : "TCP_STATE_ESTAB",
    6 : "TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT",
    7 : "TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT2",
    8 : "TCP_STATE_CLOSE_WAIT",
    9 : "TCP_STATE_CLOSING",
    10 : "TCP_STATE_LAST_ACK",
    11 : "TCP_STATE_TIME_WAIT",
    12 : "TCP_STATE_DELETE_TCB",

    "TCP_STATE_CLOSED" : 1,
    "TCP_STATE_LISTEN" : 2,
    "TCP_STATE_SYN_SENT" : 3,
    "TCP_STATE_SYN_RCVD" : 4,
    "TCP_STATE_ESTAB" : 5,
    "TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT" : 6,
    "TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT2" : 7,
    "TCP_STATE_CLOSE_WAIT" : 8,
    "TCP_STATE_CLOSING" : 9,
    "TCP_STATE_LAST_ACK" :10,
    "TCP_STATE_TIME_WAIT" : 11,
    "TCP_STATE_DELETE_TCB" : 12 }

class MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwState", DWORD),
        ("dwLocalAddr", DWORD),
        ("dwLocalPort", DWORD),
        ("dwRemoteAddr", DWORD),
        ("dwRemotePort", DWORD),
        ("dwOwningPid", DWORD)
        ]


class MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwNumEntries", DWORD),
        ("MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID", MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID * 100)
        ]



def GetExtendedTcpTable (vip=AF_INET):
    table = MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID ()
    so = sizeof (table)
    size = DWORD (so)
    order = c_int(1)

    failure= windll.iphlpapi.GetExtendedTcpTable (
        byref (table),
        addressof (size),
        order,
        vip,
        TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL,
        0    )

    assert not failure,  WinError (GetLastError ())

    pytables = []
    tables = table.MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID

    for index in range(table.dwNumEntries):
        table = tables [index]
        pytables.append (
            socket_info (
                State=states.get (table.dwState, "UNKNOWN_STATE_%s" %(str(table.dwState))),
                LocalAddr=formatip (table.dwLocalAddr),
                LocalPort=htons(table.dwLocalPort),
                RemoteAddr=formatip (table.dwRemoteAddr),
                RemotePort=htons(table.dwRemotePort),
                OwningPid = int (table.dwOwningPid)
            )
        )
    return pytables


def GetTcpTableForPid (pid):
    tables = GetExtendedTcpTable ()
    for table in tables:
        if table.OwningPid == pid: return table
    raise "Cannot find tcp table for pid %s" %pid

dict_process = {}
pid_set =set()
pid_list = []
tcp_info_list = []
tcp_info = GetExtendedTcpTable()
for item in tcp_info:
    LocalAddr = item.LocalAddr
    LocalPort = item.LocalPort
    RemoteAddr = item.RemoteAddr
    RemotePort = item.RemotePort
    OwningPid = item.OwningPid
    print('local Addr: '+ LocalAddr,'local port: '+ str(LocalPort),'remote Addr: ' + RemoteAddr, 'Remote Port: ' + str(RemotePort), OwningPid)
```

The script is run from time to time. It can run for 5 minutes and then don't work about an hour with this stupid mistake. How to get around it?

I really dont know, what's with it. Please, help me, what i do wrong?

I use python 3.2 on Win7 SP1 x64

Thank you a lot!

Comment: It looks like something in Python is overwriting the GetLastError code before you have a chance to look at it.  Try calling GetLastError *immediately* after calling GetExtendedTcpTable  - that is, outside the assert clause: `err = GetLastError() ; assert not failure, WinError(err)` -- apologies for the semicolon; python & comments don't mix well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `addressof(size)`. That returns a Python integer which will be cast as a 32-bit C `int`. Use `byref(size)` to create a pointer, which will be a 64-bit value if you're using 64-bit Python.

`GetExtendedTcpTable` doesn't call `SetLastError`. It returns a `DWORD` with one of the following codes:

```
NO_ERROR = 0
ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87
ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122
```

The `pdwSize` argument has the required size if the buffer was too small. One option here is to start with a length 0 array; then `resize` the struct; and finally `cast` the array to the correct size:

```
class MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwNumEntries", DWORD),
        ("MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID", MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID * 0),
    ]

_GetExtendedTcpTable = windll.iphlpapi.GetExtendedTcpTable

def GetExtendedTcpTable(vip=AF_INET):
    table = MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID()
    size = DWORD() 
    order = 1

    failure = _GetExtendedTcpTable(
                  byref(table),
                  byref(size),
                  order,
                  vip,
                  TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL,
                  0)

    if failure == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
        resize(table, size.value)
        memset(byref(table), 0, sizeof(table))
        failure = _GetExtendedTcpTable(
                      byref(table),
                      byref(size),
                      order,
                      vip,
                      TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL,
                      0)

    if failure: 
        raise WinError(failure)

    ptr_type = POINTER(MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID * table.dwNumEntries)
    tables = cast(table.MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID, ptr_type)[0]

    pytables = []
    for table in tables:
        # rest unchanged
```

---

Regarding the Win32 `LastError` value, in general you shouldn't rely on `GetLastError` in Python. You don't know if you're seeing an old error code from a previous call or if an intervening call modified the `LastError` value. If you're checking a single API call that uses `LastError`, then it should be OK to check `GetLastError` immediately afterward if the call failed. But more generally you may need to load the DLL with `use_last_error=True`:

```
iphlpapi = WinDLL('iphlpapi', use_last_error=True)
```

Function pointers created from this `WinDLL` instance will save `LastError` to thread local storage immediately after the call returns. Calling `get_last_error` returns the saved error code. Beforehand you can call `set_last_error(0)` to have 0 swapped in to `LastError` before the function is called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help! 
Now I using `byref(size)`, but nothing has changed. I tried to take normal error, using 
   `iphlpapi = WinDLL('iphlpapi', use_last_error=True)`
Looks like this:
`iphlpapi = WinDLL('iphlpapi', use_last_error=True)
    failure= iphlpapi.GetExtendedTcpTable (
        byref (table),
        byref (size),
        order,
        vip,
        TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL,
        0    )
    print(get_last_error())`
But it's return 0. 
I do something wrong?

Comment: Everything I said about using `get_last_error`, etc, isn't directly related to this problem; it's just general advice. Like I said, `GetExtendedTcpTable` does not use `LastError`. You have to look at the return value, `failure`. Is it 0, 87 or 122? If it's 122, you need to increase the size of the struct. I'd do that dynamically instead of assuming a fixed size.

Comment: the return value is 122. What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems, that `pdwSize` in `GetExtendetTcpTable` is too small. 
Do you know, how to get this parameter?
From MSDN:
`If this value is set too small, ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER is returned by this function, and this field will contain the correct size of the structure.`

And thank you so much!!